# Highcharts - Update a series point [x,y] values?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to update a point[x,y] in the chart.
What's the problem? 
Ok, I  chart and its chart series are like this:

```
     series: [
            {
                enableMouseTracking: false,
                name: 'Line1',
                type: 'line',
                color: '#5d5d5d',
                yAxis: 1,
                data: [[12000, 55.068493], [15064, 42.842]],
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'circle'
                }
            },
            {
                enableMouseTracking: false,
                name: 'Line2',
                type: 'line',
                color: '#5d5d5d',
                yAxis: 1,
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'circle'
                },
                data: [[12000, 57.671527], [16000, 42.620069]]

            },{
                name: 'TOM',
                //type: 'line',
                color: '#ff4100',
                yAxis: 1,
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(icons/tom.png)'
                },
                data: [
                    {
                        id:'tom_point',
                        color: '#00FF00',
                        y: fi_variable,
                        x: tom_variable
                    }
                ]
             }
```

Now the thing is that, I'm checking if `fi_variable` or `tom_variable` has changed and if its true, update these two variables, and finally update the chart.

I have tried already, some  methods like  `chart.series[0].data[0].update(y = 10);` and its working for some points with fixed x,y values, but no luck for the rest of the points.
For Instance I use `chart.series[0].data[1].update(y = 10);` will work ok,
but this `chart.series[0].data[3].update(y = 10);` will not work.

1- Is there any way to replace the `data[0]` from the above code line with an `id` of a point in our case `tom_point` ?

Also I've tried this `chart.series[0].setData([[tom_variable,fi_variable, 'tom_point']]);`
and again it wont working when the point is with an id or without fixed values.

But If I try `chart.series[0]data[0].setData([[tom_variable,fi_variable]]);` it works but again not on 3rd element (in our case - as shown above) of the series.

I can get the values for this point with the following, 
`var tomPoint = chart.get('tom_point').y;`
but I can't set any x,y values back to chart and update it (the chart).

I have also tried to check if the variables have changed and to redraw the chart with chart.redraw but nothing.

Any Ideas how can I get this to work?
Am I losing something?

Thank you in Advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution finally was simple.

I've managed to update the point:

The third element in the series with the name `TOM` corresponds to
chart.series[2].

```
               { // chart.series[2]
                name: 'TOM',
                //type: 'line',
                color: '#ff4100',
                yAxis: 1,
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(icons/tom.png)'
                },
                data: [
                    {
                        id:'tom_point',
                        color: '#00FF00',
                        y: fi_variable,
                        x: tom_variable
                    }
                ]
             }
```

So in order to update [x,y] values of this point, you have to do it like that:

`// TOM Point`

```
`chart.series[2].data[0].update({x:var_x, y:var_y});`
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all you try to update point (data[3]) which doens't exist in serie. Secondly in case when you update you need to use

`chart.series[0].data[1].update(10);` or `chart.series[0].data[1].update({y:10});` but not yoru figure

Comment: Yes thank you for pointing me that it doesn't exist that point you are right. Any other way to target at the specific x,y values and update them? When I'm trying to do the above all y:values of the series are updating.

Comment: You can use setData()

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change the x value also then use

```
chart.series[0].data[0].update({
x: 10,
y: 100
})
```

this will update both x and y values like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/DCA8W/

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: this case will work only when data is of the format data : [100.200,189,124,176]

Comment: First of all, Thank you strikers.Actually the problem is the `data[0]`, i can not point at this data (at data with id tom_point) neither with data[3] nor anything else.